# Connecting Node.js to postgres on apache server in vagrant

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript

Hello there fellow coders.
I am rebuilding my entire backend for a web application and switching from a php backend to node.js using typescript. I'm gonna reuse all my old sql files since my old database structure is sufficient.

I'm launching my node webapp via vagrant on an apache server using ansible scripts. Then I manually SSH into the VM and execute "npm start" to start my webapp. This should start my app at localhost:3000 and just show a simple "Hello world" text, just to confirm that the app is connected to postgres and running correctly.

Im really new to node and javascript/typescript so sorry in advance if I ask silly questions.

Instead of the expected behavior I get a "Failed to prune sessions: relation "session" does not exist.

My connection to postgres from the node app looks like this:

```
const app = express();
const session = require ("express-session");
const pg = require ("pg");

const Pool = require("pg-pool");



// Create a pool once per process and reuse it
const pgPool = new Pool ({
  host: localhost
  port: 5432,
  user: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  database: "test,
});

app.use(session({
  store: new(require("connect-pg-pool")(session))({
    pool: pgPool
  }),
  secret: SESSION_SECRET,
  cookie: { maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 }, // 30 days
  resave: true,
  autoreconnect: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,

}));
app.set("port", 3000);
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "../views"));
app.set("view engine", "pug");
app.get("/", homeController.index);
```

And my server.ts file is where my app listens to the port as shown below:

```
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(
    "  App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode",
    app.get("port"),
    app.get("env")
  );
  console.log("  Press CTRL-C to stop\n");
});
```

Comment: Is this solved?
What's the error on the console?

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, I had forgotten to create the sessions table for my database. "psql < node_modules/connect-pg-simple/table.sql"

Comment: Ok cool.........

Comment: Please do not spam with tags. This question has nothing to do with Ansible or Vagrant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run "psql < node_modules/connect-pg-simple/table.sql" in the project folder, this creates the session table which is used by express-session as the middleware. I had simply forgotten to do this.